# Non-re-indexing List with defragmentation

Tags: java, array, collections

I'm currently coding something where I have Objects that take on an ID, and are stored in a List. For easy retrieval, the ID of the object is it's index in the list. However, that means that the object cannot be removed from the list without everything going to hell, since the list will be re-indexed and thus I won't be able to retrieve the right object from the list by knowing its ID anymore.

I also did not want to use a Map, since that just looks ugly and makes a big part of my code look more complicated than it should.

Thus, I tried to simply use a list, but modify it in order to be able to get an index that won't change as long as the object is alive.

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SafeIndexList<E> extends ArrayList<E> {

    Stack<Integer> safeIndexes = new Stack<Integer>();

    @Override
    public E remove(int index){
        if(this.size()-1 == index) return super.remove(index);
        else {
            E e = this.get(index);
            this.set(index, null);
            safeIndexes.push(index);
            return e;
        }
    }

    public int getSafeIndex(){
        return safeIndexes.size() > 0 ? safeIndexes.pop() : size();
    }

}
```

Is this "good" or just complete, sorry for the wording, bullshit?

Comment: How do you plan to use this class from an application? The client application will add objects to the list, and then, how should it retrieve them from the list?

Comment: @sanastasiadis All the objects I push in have an ID property, which is the same as their index in the list. Some other parts of my program know the ID of the project they want to retrieve, and thus only have to call list.get(ID). That's the whole idea behind it :)

Comment: OK, so, why do you need to keep a `Stack` with `safeIndexes`? What is the added value for the client application?

Comment: @sanastasiadis Defragmentation. If I only remove values by setting them to null, the arraylist will get bigger and bigger and bigger - Thus I keep track when the value assigned to index x is set to null, so that the index can be reused. At least that's the idea behind it.

Comment: @sanastasiadis So, basically, when instantiating a new object to be inserted in there, I'll use getSafeIndex() to get both the ID of the object and the index where it is to be inserted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not complete BS. Your use-case is somewhat surprising, and your disregard for using a Map is also surprising, but given those, you're left with little option other than a completely custom implementation.... but, let's look at the issues you currently have...

People need to do a round-trip query-before-inserting operation - they need to call `getSafeIndex()` before setting a new value.

People can't use all the methods available to them. For example, they can't call:

- `clear()` (See [code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/ArrayList.java#553))
- `add(int, obj)` (See [code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.add%28int%2Cjava.lang.Object%29))
- ..... none of the iterator, or stream-related methods (foreach, etc.) because they will return null values mixed in the wrong places.
- `size()` will lie to them.

... in fact, the only methods that can be used reliably are `set(...)`, `get(...)`, and similar ones.

Extending `ArrayList` seems to introduce a lot of ways to break the code/data integrity.

I recommend encapsulation instead. In fact, this is a common "debate": Inheritance vs. Composition/Encapsulation (search for those topics on google).

In this case, composition/encapsulation would remove a lot of your issues, and reduce the class to just what you need.

Underlying your class you could still have the ArrayList and Stack, (except `Stack` class is deprecated in favour of `Deque` interfaces) but it would look something like:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SafeIndexList<E> {

    List<E> data = new ArrayList<>();
    Deque<Integer> safeIndexes = new ArrayDeque<>();

    public E remove(int index){
        if(index < data.size())
            // check double-removes.
            if (!safeIndexes.contains(index)) {
                safeIndexes.push(index);
            }
            return super.remove(index);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public int add(E value){
        int idx = safeIndexes.isEmpty() ? data.size() : safeIndexes.pop();
        data.set(idx, value);
        return idx;
    }

}
```

You can add methods for other features you need, as needed. Note, that having abstracted/encapsulated the underlying data store mechanism, you can easily replace the array/deque with a Map now, and not notice.

***Edit***: to add in the combined constructor/index problem, a solution like this may help, adding the method:

```
    public int construct(IntFunction<E> factory) {
        int idx = safeIndexes.isEmpty() ? data.size() : safeIndexes.pop();
        data.set(idx, factory.apply(idx));
        return idx;
    }
```

Now, you can call that with something like:

```
int id = mylist.construct(i -> new MyObject(..., i, ...));
```

The above constructs the inner object with the index, but "internal" to the list too. Alternatively, you can return the constructed object if that makes more sense....

```
MyObject obj = mylist.construct(i -> new MyObject(..., i, ...));
```

Comment: Also, one remaining "problem" I have (That could be worked around of, but which would look ugly): The objects I store in the list need their ID in their constructor. Whichs means that I can't just `myObject.ID = add(myObject);` (Simple for reasons of safety). I'm thus not quite sure how to properly work around that issue... Also, overloading operators would be nice, so that I could loop `for(Obj o : mySafeIndexList`, instead of having to call `mySafeIndexList.data` (which is supposed to be private/protected)

Comment: Well, that constructor problem is a problem... it requires close coupling with the list, which is not good.... but could be solved by adding a factory method on your list that constructs the object for you. You could pass in a construction method as part of the list constructor... let me edit an example in to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to map IDs to Objects, then Map is the right choice (HashMap as the implementation):

```
Map<Integer, Object> objectMap = new HashMap<>();
```

I cannot imagine Map-based solution being harder to create and maintain than the `SafeIndexList`...